# Apache Wicket FormTester not working properly

Tags: apache, wicket

there is a problem where I am struggling and cannot find anything useful in the web. I have a form with wicketID "addressform" which is a panel inside of Main template class. I am trying to test it as follows:

```
    public void testLinkToAddressFormValid(){
    PageParameters params = new PageParameters();
    params.add("entity", "address");
    params.add("viewMode", "2");
    params.add("subMode", "0");
    params.add("key", "1");

    // start Main Page with given parameters
    tester.startPage(Main.class, params);

    // try to test a new form
    FormTester formTester = tester.newFormTester("addressform",false);
    formTester.submit();
    }
```

Normally I call the address form by using

```
    setResponsePage(new Main("address",2,0,1));
```

which replaces the content of the main template with the AddressForm (class is called AddressForm whcih extends Panel) Panel. The AddressForm takes some parameters.

In the end I get the exception "junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: path: 'addressform' does not exist for page: Main". At the moment I am using Apache Wicket 6.0

Answer (score 0):

Assert that actually Main page is rendered after startPage() call. Maybe you have an authentication strategy that redirects to a login page?!

Comment: Hey martin, thanks for the hint. Of course, there is an authentication mechanism, but before the test cases run there is a method which does the authentication. The strange thing here is that it shows me that addressform would not exist for page Main, but Main is my template and addressform a panel which is rendered inside the template. Could it be that we need to take another path for newFormTester() call? Maybe something like panel:addressform?

Comment: Use tester.debugComponentTrees() to see the components structure.